# Does the word "dashily" exist in English?

Tags: meaning, is-it-a-word

Could someone, please say if the word "dashily" exists? I couldn't find one in any vocabularies. A few hours ago I saw this [web clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-rrxeyA5do#t=51) (The Vampire Diaries), and beginning from **00:40** Damon says:

> And listen, despite the fact that my long list of ***dashily*** deeds involves killing you, I'm glad you're alive.

Maybe, I can't hear the word correctly, and there must be another one. Please, help me understand what it is and what it means. I'd really appreciate any help. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[dastardly](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dastardly)

> ADJECTIVE dated or humorous
>
> Wicked and cruel:
>
> *pirates and their dastardly deeds*

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot. You made my day, 'cause I thought I'm crazy, lol :))))))

Comment: @Ksiencha, no problem! :)

Comment: @Ksiencha - Don't worry about it. The word was not clearly pronounced in that clip. I think that only people who knew the word and the contexts in which it is often used would have recognised it.

Comment: As a child of the ’80s and ’90s, I cannot see or hear this word without fond memories of [Dick Dastardly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dick_Dastardly) popping into my mind.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: exactly the same here. :)

Comment: And Ksiencha, please note the "dated or humorous" in the definition above: this is not an everyday word.

Comment: @ColinFine is dead right, [this is the kind of scenario where the word 'dastardly' would be appropriate](http://theoneyearchallenge.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/damsel-in-distress.jpg).